# Can You Install Windows Twice With MBR Partitioning?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

My partition layout is MBR with System Reserved partition, recovery partition and Windows partition as Windows partitions.

The fourth primary partition is an extended partition with several logical partitions within it for linux.

I am considering a clean install of Windows but don't want to delete my existing install.

If I shrink my existing Windows partition to make free space I would have enough space for a new install.

However, since I already have 4 primary partitions I wouldn't be able to add a new one for an extra Windows install.

- Is it possible to install Windows in a logical partition in the extended partition?
- Does Windows need the boot and recovery partition?
- What happens if I delete the existing boot and recovery partitions and then try to install Windows in the free space?
- Will it still try to create 3 partitions for the new install?
- Can you even specify which partition to install Windows in or does it take over the entire disk by default?

Comment: On the same machine at the same time with the same license?  You can only run one license at a time, so would have to put data on a USB hard drive to transfer. Easier (much) to put your data, email, program install packages on a USB hard drive and do a fresh install of Windows and then recover everything

Comment: Its easier to leave the existing partition then mount it and copy the files across than to do a partition/disk backup and recover items from that image or try to remember everywhere on disk that you had any relevant files and only copy those.

Comment: I specified that I have Windows and linux in my partitions. Why are you asking about mac?

Comment: Sorry, I answer so may Mac question over in [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com). I did not notice I am in superuser.

Answer (score 1):

- Is it possible to install Windows in a logical partition in the extended partition?

  Yes, but you need to boot Windows from a primary partition.
- Does Windows need the boot and recovery partition?

  If you do not have a boot partition, then the boot files will be stored in a the hidden `Boot` folder. If you do not have a recovery partition, then Windows will install with the recovery files stored in the hidden `Recovery` folder.
- What happens if I delete the existing boot and recovery partitions and then try to install Windows in the free space?

  You can recreate the boot files in the Windows partition so you will not need a separate boot partition. You should move your recovery files to your Windows partition hidden `Recovery` folder. Or, lose the recovery files when you delete the partition.
- Will it still try to create 3 partitions for the new install?

  The Windows installer GUI can create additional partitions. Sometimes you can circumvent this by first creating the partitions. For example, with `diskpart`. You can also install Windows using the CLI which offers more flexibility.
- Can you even specify which partition to install Windows in or does it take over the entire disk by default?

  You can specify exactly where you want the Windows files installed. However, you may need to use the CLI to do this.

The usual arrangement for dual boot Windows is to have the newest version of Windows host a boot manager. This allow you to select which Windows to run when booting. However, you can also setup a dual boot where the active partition must be changed in the MBR in order to change which Windows boots.

The requires are given in the Microsoft website [BIOS/MBR-based hard drive partitions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-biosmbr-based-hard-drive-partitions).